# Como agregar contenido a base de datos con PDO sin sobrescribir el contenido

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hola me gustaria saber como puedo anexar unos datos a una fila que tengo en mi base de datos, he intentado varios metodos, algunos no me funcionan y otros simplemente actualizan los datos y los sobreescriben. Lo que necesito es que este se agregue sin borrar los datos existentes, actualmente tengo este codigo.

```
$valor1 = (empty($_POST['dato1'])) ? " " : $_POST['dato1'];
$valor2 = (empty($_POST['dato2'])) ? " " : $_POST['dato2'];
$id = (empty($_POST['id'])) ? " " : $_POST['id'];

$sql_editar = 'UPDATE cueva SET rutaA=?,rutaB=? WHERE id=?';
$sentencia_editar = $pdo->prepare($sql_editar);
$sentencia_editar->execute(array($valor1,$valor2,$id));

//cerramos conexión base de datos y sentencia
$pdo = null; 
$sentencia_editar = null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A qué te refieres con anexar? puedes poner un ejemplo de el resultado que necesitas? 
Si solo quieres concatenar puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$valor1 = (empty($_POST['dato1'])) ? " " : $_POST['dato1'];
$valor2 = (empty($_POST['dato2'])) ? " " : $_POST['dato2'];
$id = (empty($_POST['id'])) ? " " : $_POST['id'];

$sql_editar = 'UPDATE cueva SET rutaA=CONCAT(rutaA,?), rutaB=CONCAT(rutaB,?) WHERE id=?';
$sentencia_editar = $pdo->prepare($sql_editar);
$sentencia_editar->execute(array($valor1,$valor2,$id));

//cerramos conexión base de datos y sentencia
$pdo = null; 
$sentencia_editar = null;
```

Comment: PERFECTO! es exactamente lo que necesitaba, estaba tratando de incorporar CONCAT ya que lo había visto en otras sentencias diferentes a PDO, pero no conté con suerte. Muchas gracias por la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que se me ocurre es hacerlo en dos partes:
1º Un select, para coger los datos
2º Un update, con los datos del select y los nuevos.

Comment: Y mientras coges y actualizas puede ocurrir cualquier cosa en la BBDD. Se puede hacer directamente en una transacción como han propuesto mas abajo.

Comment: Bueno, puedes hacer un procedure, y llamarlo.

Comment: ¿Y para que vas a montar un procedure pudiendo hacerlo en una sentencia mucho mas simple?

Comment: El procedure vas a poner el codigo una vez. Despues solo lo llamas. Si pretende usar esto mas veces solo vale para este caso. El procedure es mas rapido, ya que es el propio motor. Como dice en el comentario anterior: "Y mientras coges y actualizas puede ocurrir cualquier cosa en la BBDD" y evitas lock tables

Comment: Eso de que es mas rapido no lo tengas tan claro, La parte de la comunicación entre PHP y mysql puede darte sorpresas. Aparte que con procedure por defecto no te evitas lo que pueda ocurrir si hay mas peticiones.

Comment: Yo nunca he tenido ningun problema con los procedures y PHP.

Comment: Eso no indica que no existan.

Comment: Entiendo que un procedure es exagerar, e insisto en lo mas fácil, cuando el programador vaya cogiendo experiencia, el por su cuenta vera que lo mejor es la sentencia preparada.